# Buck converter mains voltage

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, mains, 5v

I'm working in a buck converter to step down **127VDC** to **5VDC/1A**. I know that boost converters have limitations, thus it's not recommended to step up **5VDC** to **127VDC**. But I couldn't find anything about buck converter limitations. After Reading [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva477b/slva477b.pdf) document from TI I figured out some values for inductors, capacitors and so on. But my doubts still remain: *Is it okay to step down that amount of volts? Will I find any trouble with my common buck converter circuit?*

Obs.: The load will be constant and it is not sensitive to voltage oscillation around the **5V** tension.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCnsi4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A usb power supply would probably work just as well.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I really would like to learn more about buck converters and it's possible applications on rectified mains voltage. So, no _easy way_ this time :3 .

Comment: High ratio can be achieved but is not common due to the limitations several people have mentioned.  I designed a 12-200 VDC in / 12 DCout buck converter for use in exercise equipment that used an alternator as the user load. It worked but efficiency was low near Vout max. Still FAR better than a linear regulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem with a large voltage ratio buck converter is that the duty-cycle becomes very small - the ratio of the voltages - and if you maintain a reasonable frequency of operation the ON time gets very short.

Also the way you have it here with an N-channel FET the PWM signal is required to be over 130V in amplitude - this will be difficult to create, especially as it is above the maximum Vgs of the switching FET.

A buck converter is non-isolating so the output is galvanically connected to the AC input - potentially a safety issue.

Also - why do you specify 127V as the input? If it is really AC line power at 120V when you rectify it you will get ~165V.

The normal solution to all these problems for low to medium power is a flyback converter using a transformer.  These can be very simple, although it is usually simpler to purchase a ready made unit.

[image: Simple line powered flyback SMPS]

From [SMPS schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/207940/smps-schematic-transformer-calculator/208020)

[Design Guide for Flyback Converter](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-4137.pdf)

Comment: Yeah, you are right man, I forgot to edit that voltage values (in fact, AC lines are 127V here). According to that TI paper that I mentioned, the duty cicyle will be 3.3% and frequency 100kHz. Is it possible to work? Considering the modifications that you proposed for the MOSFET. I will consider the flyback design, I really liked the idea.

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Another drawback of high voltage ratio buck (and boost) converters is the need for both switching devices (MOSFET and diode in this case) to withstand both the full input voltage *and* the peak inductor current. In a transformer -based DC/DC converter (like a flyback) this isn't the case.

Comment: @Kevin White, not sure about the winding dots but considering the two diodes and the output inductor \$L_2\$ it looks like you've inserted the picture of a forward converter : ) Most of the small non-isolated converters found in the white-goods market are buck converters (up to 276 V rms). A tapped version can help for the duty ratio but the flyback converter is the easiest way for low-power isolated stuff.

Comment: @VerbalKint - good catch.  My error - Sorry about that, more haste less speed.

Comment: @Kevin White, no problem. I can see you have inserted the pix of a nice ringing-choke converter. I remember seeing these in cell-phone chargers back in 1997. They don't like to be unloaded (at least this simple version) hence the fairly chubby bleeder in the output.

Comment: @VerbalKint - I was looking for something simple enough to see the operation.  Agreed being self-oscillating it has its limitations.